# Does Cauchy-Schwarz imply $|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_p\|y\|_p$ for any $p \geq 1$?

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the Cauchy Schwarz inequality states,

$|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_2\|y\|_2$

And for non-Euclidean (norms other than $l_2$), we have,

$|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_p\|y\|_q$ where $\|\cdot\|_q$ is the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|_p$ (I remember $p,q$ is related by $1/p+1/q = 1$ or something like that)

For example,
$|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_1\|y\|_\infty$

My question is:

> Does Cauchy-Schwarz imply $|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_p\|y\|_p$ for any $p
>  \geq 1$?

I feel like this should hold, based on the fact that all the norms are equivalent. In the previous example, we know that $\|y\|_\infty \leq \alpha \|y\|_1$ with some constant $\alpha$ (I can never remind the exact number)

Then it must be true that,
$|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_1\|y\|_1$

Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: We do have $|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_p \|y\|_p$ for $1 \leq p \leq 2$, but not for $p>2$.

Comment: The norms are equivalent indeed. But the constants in the norm comparison DO matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... we know that $\|y\|_\infty \leq \alpha \|y\|_1$ with some constant $\alpha$ ...

Well, actually we have $\|y\|_\infty \leq  \|y\|_1$, and that implies
$$
|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_1\|y\|_\infty \le  \|x\|_1\|y\|_1 \, ,
$$
so that your reasoning is essentially correct for $p=1$.

For $p > 1$ the same approach works as long as the conjugate $q$ (defined by $\frac 1p  + \frac 1q = 1$ ) satisfies $p \le q$, that is, if $p \le 2$. Then [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) and  the [relation between $p$-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms) gives
$$
|x^Ty| \leq \|x\|_p\|y\|_q \le \|x\|_p\|y\|_p \, .
$$

The same reasoning does not work if $p > 2$, and in fact the desired estimate does not hold in that case. This can be seen by choosing  $x = y \ne 0$:
$$
|x^Ty| = \Vert x \Vert_2^2 > \Vert x \Vert_p^2 = \|x\|_p\|y\|_p \, .
$$

*Summary:* 
$$
|x^Ty| \leq \Vert x\Vert_p\Vert y\Vert _p  \text{ for all } x, y \in \Bbb R^n 
$$
holds if and only if $p \le 2$.

Comment: Hi, I don't see how you obtained the inequality in the line $
|x^Ty| = \Vert x \Vert_2^2 > \Vert x \Vert_p^2 = \|x\|_p\|y\|_p \, .
$ Why shouldn't the inequality be flipped?

Comment: @Aåkon: The p-norm is *decreasing*in p: $p > 2$ implies $\Vert x \Vert_p < \Vert x \Vert_2$